# little jquery calculation

Tags: jquery

I need some simple calculations done using jquery.

This example http://jsfiddle.net/tbL5r/ is pretty close. It just needs a little tweaking:

1. the user should input the price.
2. I need the sum of the all prices calculated.
3. It should calculate without clicking buttons.

Cheers and Thanks

Comment: We're happy to help with specific problems you're having but we're not here to do your work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

give this a try: http://jsfiddle.net/tbL5r/38/

```
$(".price").blur(function(){
    var total = 0;
    $(".price").each(function(){
        if(!isNaN(this.value)){
            total += Number(this.value);
        }
    });
    $(".target").html(Math.round(total * 100) / 100);  
});
```

Comment: thanks for your help, can math.round run before creating a total so that each input can have a unique math. say input id="1" would calculate (Math.round(total * 100) / 50) and input id="2" would calculate (Math.round(total * 100) / 75)

Comment: I think so I'm however not a 100% sure of what you're going for here, maby you should create a new more specific question about this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where u wanted the user input price to go into the equation so you can decide than but it all works as you described :)

```
<input id="number" type="text" />
<p class="price">1<p>
<p class="price">33.33</p>
<p class="price">0.3</p>


$('#number').keyup(function() {
    var = price $(this).val();
    $('p.price').text(function(i,v) {
        return Math.round(parseInt(v * 100, 10) * 7.5) / 100;
    });


});
```